# MYSQL Number of employees worked in specific years department wise

Tags: mysql, join

Hello  i am new to writing sql queries
i want to display the number of workers worked in 2013,2014,2015  respectively.

MY CODE TO FIND NUMBER OF  EMPLOYEES ON DEPARTMENTS IS

```
     SELECT d.department_id,d.department_name,
     COUNT('e.emp_id') "number of employees"
      FROM master_department d,master_employee e
     WHERE d.department_id = e.department
      GROUP BY d.department_id,d.department_name
```

in the emp_resign table there is  resignation_date AND
in  emp table there is joining date.
How can i compare these dates to find number of employees worked  on these specific years

Code To find workers in specific year is

```
            SELECT   d.department_id,d.department_name,COUNT(e.emp_id) 
                    AS Emp_sum_2015
                    FROM          master_employee AS e INNER JOIN
                    employee_resign AS er ON e.emp_id = er.emp_id
                    INNER JOIN  master_department d ON  d.department_id = e.department

         WHERE (YEAR(e.joining_date) <= 2015) AND (YEAR(er.date_of_resign) >= 2015 OR
                     YEAR(er.date_of_resign) IS NULL)
                     GROUP BY d.department_id,d.department_name
```

Comment: do u have a log/initial date field in your table?

Comment: Try to go through standard books.....

Comment: ...date FROM... WHERE date IN(...) GROUP BY department_id, date

Comment: @HarikaB  i have join_date field in  emp table   and  resignation_date in emp_resign table

Comment: @ustaad it has to be 1 query? not 3 queries for each year?

Comment: @JanWalczak   the query i wrote here only finds number of employees department wise. i m stuck with finding active employees in each year.

Comment: @ustaad i got it, but it has to be 1 query for all that 2013, 2014, 2015 years or can i help You with query lets say for 2013 only and u can use it 3 times?

Comment: @JanWalczak    i need one query for these years..

Answer (score 0):

I can help You to do this for certaing year.

Let's say Yours emp table schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[emp](
    [emp_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Join_date] [date] NOT NULL)
```

and Yours emp_resign:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[emp_resign](
    [Resign_Id] [int] NULL,
    [emp_id] [int] NULL,
    [resignation_date] [date] NULL
)
```

The number of Employees who worked in 2015 u can get from this query:

```
 SELECT        COUNT(e.emp_id) AS Emp_sum_2015
FROM            dbo.emp AS e LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.emp_resign AS er ON e.emp_id = er.emp_id
WHERE        (YEAR(e.Join_date) <= 2015) AND (YEAR(er.resignation_date) >= 2015 OR
                         YEAR(er.resignation_date) IS NULL)
```

Comment: great! , i redited your query according to my requirements ,u can see it on my question, and  is there any way to  find workers of all threee years in single query?

Answer (score 0):

You could use group by. I am editing the query you added in your question:

```
SELECT  YEAR(e.joining_date), d.department_id,d.department_name,COUNT(e.emp_id) 
                    AS Emp_sum_2015
                    FROM          master_employee AS e INNER JOIN
                    employee_resign AS er ON e.emp_id = er.emp_id
                    INNER JOIN  master_department d ON  d.department_id = e.department

         WHERE (YEAR(e.joining_date) <= 2013) AND (YEAR(er.date_of_resign) >= 2015 OR
                     YEAR(er.date_of_resign) IS NULL)
                     GROUP BY YEAR(e.joining_date),d.department_id,d.department_name
```

Could you give it a try and let me know if it works..

Comment: yea i tried it with some slight changes.  thank yew :)

Comment: Vote up the answer if it solved the issue..it gives an idea whether or not issue is resolved..

Comment: because my repution is below 15  ,my upvote is only recorded  not shown